# UPDATE table using a subquery in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

I want to update records from a sub-query. I am using the following query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET a = aa FROM (SELECT a AS aa FROM table2) AS abc WHERE f = 1
```

This works fine in SQL Server. But doesn't work in SQLite.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support `UPDATE ... FROM`. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html